# How Do I Center This Middle Image?

Tags: html, css

i'm having trouble centering the middle image...tried margin:0 auto, tried inline-block, etc. what am i forgetting here?

need a solution that will work on all browsers.

JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NuFtA/3/

here's the css:

```
.class2{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.class3{
float:right;
```

Comment: is this kind of what you look for ? http://jsfiddle.net/NuFtA/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can re-arrange the HTML to:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" class="class1" width="100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" class="class3" width="100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" class="class2" width="100" />
```

Then this CSS will do it:

```
.class1 {
    float:left;
}
.class2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
.class3 {
    float:right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NuFtA/5/)**

Comment: thank you, this worked and was better than having to mess with text-align since that doesn't always work on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NuFtA/10/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" class="image class1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" class="image class2" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400" class="image class3" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image_container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

.class1{
    left: 0;
}

.class2{
    margin-left: -50px; /* Half of the image's width*/
}

.class3{
    right: 0;
}
```